# windows c# wpf / GetCommandLineArgs and registry shell open issue

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, registry

My program allows the user to open a file directly with it.

To do so, I've created a registry key that open the program with the path of the file as first parameters.

so this is my registry key :

```
C:\Users\path_to\program.exe %1
```

Here, `%1` is the specified path.

In simple path, like `C:\Users\path\path\file.png` it's works; perfectly.

**But** when I chose to open a special path (with **spaces**, for example) I've got something like that : `C:\Users\path\DOCUME~\BROKEN~\path_ok~\FILE~1`
-> `BROKEN~` is a path with spaces in it, normaly it's like `broken path test`.

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Use "%1" in the key value, i.e. with double quotes

Comment: ow, well. Thanks 
You can post the answer, I'll validate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The path with tildas (~) is a valid path to your file. You can try openng the file with that path and you will see that it works.

Windows used to limit each path component to 8 characters and not allow spaces in path components. When these restrictions were first lifted, most program could not handle the new path names, so Windows would also assign an old-form path name to each file that had spaces or path components longer than 8 characters. The path with tildas that you see is such old-form path.

Of course most software now, can handle regular paths, but Windows still provides maintains the old-form paths (even Windows 10).

You can tell Windows that you support new paths if your register your program with

```
C:\Users\path_to\program.exe "%1"
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\path_to\program.exe %1
```